# Tengo problemas con mi placa esp6288 y un DHT11 sensor humedad y temperatura

Tags: arduino

me encuentro teniendo problemas al momento de flashear el codigo en un IDE arduino a mi placa
Simplemente me aparece el siguiente mensaje[image: El error]
Tengo los puertos conectados y reconocidos
el router esta cerca
[image: configuracion]

Ayudaa!

Answer (score 0):

Una vez cometí un error que me dio el mismo mensaje.

Tenía un ESP9266 con un DHT11 para monitorear temperatura/humedad ambiente.

Nunca tuve problemas para **actualizar** programas (MicroPython), pero cuando trate de flashear una nueva versión de MicroPython, me salio el mensaje de marras.

Claro, tenía conectado el pin GPIO0 (D3 en mi tarjeta) con el DTH11.

El ESP8266 no bootea si el GPIO0 esta en LOW.

Esta [guía te dice los pines](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-pinout-reference-gpios/) que puedes usar.

Espero que sea eso.